# Laravel Getting id's from a table and inserting them into another table

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to get matching `id's` from a table  and inserting them again in the same table under differnet relationship.

```
$contentPack = ContentPack::find($id);
$cloned_pack_goals = DB::table('content_pack_goal')->where('content_pack_id' , $contentPack->id)->get();
$cloned_pack_goal_ids = $cloned_pack_goals->goal_id;
```

Produces Exception

```
Exception
Property [goal_id] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

`dd($cloned_pack_goals);` outputs:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#2466 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => {#3129 ▼
          +"goal_id": 4
          +"content_pack_id": 2
        }
        1 => {#2467 ▼
          +"goal_id": 9
          +"content_pack_id": 2
        }
      ]
    }
```

How to get `goal_ids` from the output to insert them into the same table again but with a different relation?

```
$newPack = $contentPack->replicate();
DB::table('content_pack_goal')->insert(['content_pack_id' => $newPack->id,'goal_id' => $cloned_pack_goal_ids]);
```

Am doing something wrong when getting the ID's and when inserting them. tried using `->first();` it works but only one `id` gets inserted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$cloned_pack_goals is a collection, so you need to exclude goal_ids from all collection records separately.
This snippet may help you:

```
$cloned_pack_goal_ids = DB::table('content_pack_goal')->where('content_pack_id' , $contentPack->id)->pluck('goal_id')->toArray();

foreach($cloned_pack_goal_ids as $key => $goal_id) {
   DB::table('content_pack_goal')->insert(['content_pack_id' => $newPack->id,'goal_id' => $goal_id]);

}
```

Comment: maybe you can check this question if you got an idea?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72304062/laravel-api-controller-return-object-along-with-other-arguments

Answer (score 0):

To get an array of only the Ids, use `pluck()` and `toArray()`

```
$cloned_pack_goal_ids = DB::table('content_pack_goal')
    ->where('content_pack_id' , $contentPack->id)
    ->pluck('goal_id') // returns a collection of only Ids.
    ->toArray(); // returns an array from the collection.
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your query in this format this will give you the require output:

```
$cloned_pack_goals = DB::table('content_pack_goal')->where('content_pack_id' , $contentPack->id)->get()->toArray();
$cloned_pack_goal_ids = $cloned_pack_goals[0]->goal_id;
```